# Need help for Dynamic Dropdownlist in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Does anyone know how to do dynamic dropdownlist in ASP? I have two dropdownlist. First will display all states. From the state, the second dropdownlist will display all the hotel name based on the state just now. Finally, when the user select one hotel, for example Hotel ABC, it will display the Hotel ABC information. All the information will be retrieve from database.

Can anyone help me with this. Need advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Daisy, thats a really BIG question. Yes it is doable but you're asking for alot of information/code. I'd suggest you might want to learn more about ASP first, pulling data from DB's, etc. Sounds like you might not have the inital skill set yet to understand the code that might be posted which would just lead to more problems.

Comment: Classic ASP, or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

This example uses Javascript, with asp and database interaction. I have used this example for something similar to what you want:

http://www.plus2net.com/asp-tutorial/db-dropdown.php

Answer (score 0):

create a function that on selected index change of teh state drop down gets the hotel list from the db then populates the hotel drop down. make another function that is called on selected index change of the hotel drop down that get the hotel info and popultes the appropriate fields